# Tags in Datadog for autoscaling_group when using metrics have changed? (Now aws_autoscaling_groupname)

Tags: amazon-web-services, datadog, aws-auto-scaling

We have monitors and dashboards templated in Terraform that are used when creating new accounts and have found that ones using queries by "autoscaling_group" now report no data.

Looking in metrics I can see the only option for grouping by ASG is "aws_autoscaling_groupname" but can't seem to find where this is set. [AWS Auto Scaling integration documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_auto_scaling/) also shows that this should be autoscaling_group.

Where can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the Autoscaling group via the Terraform `aws_autoscaling_group` resource, then there's a `name` parameter that is distinct from the **resource** name.

An example that shows the difference:

```
resource "aws_placement_group" "prod-asg" {
  name     = "application123"
  strategy = "cluster"
}
```

In this example, when generating dashboards, the ASG name you want to add to widgets would be `application123`, which should end up as the `autoscaling_group` name in Datadog.

If using Terraform to build the dashboard widgets, then the reference would be something like this:

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "monitoring" {
  title = "..."
  widget {
    type = "timeseries"
    title = "..."
    request {
      q = "avg:aws.autoscaling.desired_capacity{name:${aws_autoscaling_group.prod-asg.name}}.as_count()"
    }
  }
}
```

Refs: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group